# Nested Query in SOQL

Tags: salesforce, soql, cloveretl

Can someone please help me generate SOQL for the below query.
Getting this error - Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported

```
SELECT External_ID_vod__c, FirstName, LastName, Middle_vod__c  
FROM Account
where Id IN (select Account_vod__c from EM_Attendee_vod__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT  Incurred_Expense_Attendee_vod__c
FROM Expense_Header_vod__c 
where CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) > 2020 and Status_vod__c = 'Paid_in_Full_vod'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with WHERE clauses you can go "down" the related list only 1 level, looks like you'd need 2 levels.

Couple ideas.

**Can you do it in 2 steps**? First `select Account_vod__c from EM_Attendee_vod__c...`, then pass the results to 2nd query.

See if you can eliminate a level by using **rollup summary fields** - but with this case might be tricky, rollup of all payments in 2020 might be not possible.

See if you can run a report that's close to what you need (even if it'd only grab these `Account_vod__c`) and you could use "[reporting snapshot](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_defining_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)" - save the intermediate results of the report in a helper custom object. That could make it easier to query.

See if you can **run the query by going "up"**. For example `Account_vod__c` is a real lookup/master-detail you could try with something like

```
select Account_vod__r.External_ID_vod__c, Account_vod__r.FirstName, Account_vod__r.LastName, Account_vod__r.Middle_vod__c
from EM_Attendee_vod__c
WHERE Id IN (SELECT  Incurred_Expense_Attendee_vod__c
FROM Expense_Header_vod__c 
where CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) > 2020 and Status_vod__c = 'Paid_in_Full_vod')
```

It's not perfect, it'd give you duplicate accounts if they have multiple attendees but it could work good enough. And in a pinch you could always try to deduplicate it with a `GROUP BY Account_vod__r.External_ID_vod__c, Account_vod__r.FirstName, Account_vod__r.LastName, Account_vod__r.Middle_vod__c` (although GROUP BY doesn't like to have more than 200 results... you could then cheat with LIMIT + [OFFSET](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm) if you expect to have 2K accounts max)